# table multicolumn: even rows under odd rows

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

I've been searching this for a while without finding a good solution.
I need to make this table:

[image: Business Model Canvas]

The problem appears when trying to make a row with 5 columns and right below it a row with 2 columns: With the vertical line just below the third column of the other row.

Is there a good way to achive this?

Note: I Don't want to use the TIKZ package.

Note: I already tryed to put two tabular inside a table but I don't like the result, like this:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-2}
 & f & & g &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7.7cm}|p{7.6cm}|}
h & i \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Any help will be great.
Grettings.

## Edited: ##

Trying to use Przemysław Scherwentke suggestion I have:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm} |c| c |p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm}|}
\hline
a & b &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}   & d & e \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-2}
  & f & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text of c} & g &  \\ 
  \hline
\multicolumn{3}{p(2.8cm}|}{h} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{i} \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

\end{table}

which gives me the error:

```
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (2): `c' used.
See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.57     \multicolumn{3}{p(2.8cm}|
                              }{h} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{i} \\
```

close

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do the cells need to have a prescribed height?

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks. No, they don't, I'll just put text there in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is some manual work, but changing 
`\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}`
onto, say,
`\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}cc|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}`
and then in place of `cc` using `\multicolumn{2}{p{2.8cm}|}{your text}`,
and in the last row using `\multicolumn{5}` etc. should give the desired result.

Comment: Przemyslaw, Thanks for the quick answer!
I tryed what you suggested, but it seems to be a problem when using the line \multicolumn{2}{p(2.8cm}|}{your text}
when using c.
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (2): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.57     \multicolumn{3}{p(2.8cm}|
                                  }{h} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{i} \\

Comment: @Sam You duplicated my misprint. Instead of `{p(2.8cm}|}` there should be `{p{2.8cm}|}` (the opening was `(` not `{`). Corrected now in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Done! thanks Przemysław Scherwentke.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm} |p{1.4cm}| p{1.4cm} |p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm}|}
\hline
a & b &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{c}   & d & e \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-2}
  & f & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text of c} & g &  \\ 
  \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{7cm}}{h} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{i} \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Thanks!